# Redirect Calls for specific File Extension

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect any calls to a specific file extension (here .jphp) to another url, using the filename part of the call as a subfolder. I try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule [^/]/([^\.jphp])\.jphp /js/$1/
```

It should ignore anything before the last "/", then store the Filename in $1 and redirect to HOST/js//
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `^` as the first character in a regex character class `[]` is an inversion. `[^/]` evaluates to "any character that is NOT a slash", and the `[^\.jphp]` evalutes to "any charater that is NOT a `.`, `j`, `p` or `h`.

Since you're not specifying charater repetition limits, you're limiting your urls to be of the form

x/z.jphp

where x and z are any single characters which are NOT one of the excluded characters mentioned above.